# Print character at coordinates in C

Tags: c, console-application, c-standard-library

I wanted to write a vi-like text editor for Linux in C (just as a personal exercise) and I realized that it would be really useful if I could print a character in a precise position in C. Is there a function from the standard library that accomplishes this? Something like:

```c
int PrintAt(int x, int y, char c);
```

Comment: Look into curses.

Comment: "Curses" is absolutely the library you're looking for.  See [Getting Started with ncurses](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/getting-started-ncurses), [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/), among many other resources.  Have fun :)

Comment: Yes, it does support ANSI escape, but I really want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be to use ANSI escape sequences. there is a sequence that moves the cursor to a XY position, and then you can print things over there.

the escape sequence looks like this: `\033[x;yH`
x and y being the location, so to easily move the location, you can define a simple macro that will do the trick, or put it in your function.

Macro-way:
`#define cursorXY(x,y) printf("\033[%d;%dH",(x),(y))`

Function-way:

```
void PrintAt(int x, int y, char c)
{
   printf("\033[%d;%dH%c", x, y, c);
}
```

(Note the top left corner is (0, 0) on the screen)

Comment: [CSI (Control Sequence Introducer) sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences) implies 1,1 is the top left.

Comment: Macro has `(y),(x)` and function has `x, y`.  The order of one of those is amiss.

Comment: Also note the questioner's comment `"Yes, it does support ANSI escape, but I really want to avoid that."` -- so while this is an option, it may not be the option looked for.  Though the ANSI escapes are essentially the option for VT compatible terminals unless a curses package is used.

Comment: But he did say he wanted something that was standard, and ANSI sequences are supported on linux, windows, and mac, so its basically standard. you dont need to use (n)curses for it.